# Confuse about the usage and the place to register a service in angular 2

Tags: angular

All:

First day in Angular2, when I followed its official TUTORIAL at part 6: Routing Around the App

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

Under `Create AppComponent` part,  it says:

- Add HeroService to the providers array of AppModule because we'll
  need it in every other view.
- Remove HeroService from the
  HeroesComponent providers array since it has been promoted.

I thought the reason to `Add HeroService to the providers array of AppModule` is  for using it without import/declare it over and over again in each component, but when I open `heroes.component.ts` example file, it still import that service:

```
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
```

This makes me so confused, **what is the point of registering a service in providers meta field of AppModule if we still need to import HeroService in each file which needs it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `providers` entry is for Angular 2's dependency injection infrastructure and the `import` is for the TypeScript types.

When you use the service in your component, the dependency injection infrastructure will create the instance - using the provider information in the `NgModule`. However, for static type checking the TypeScript `import` is still required and, in some cases, the type itself is what identifies the DI provider. If the service was provided using something other than the actual type - an `OpaqueToken`, for example - and was declared as `any` where injected, you would not need the `import`.

Comment: Thanks, another question is : what will happen if I register that HeroService both in AppModule and HeroesComponent, when the HeroesComponent get called, I wonder that injected instance should from  which one? Should it be from the closed level?

Comment: Of that, I'm not so sure. `NgModule` was introduced fairly late in the release cycle and my experience with its `providers` interactions is limited. I'd guess that it would use the service declared in the component's `providers`, but it's just a guess.

Comment: @Kuan When you add it the `@Component.providers`, the service is only scoped to its components and subcomponents, meaning every time the component is created, a new service is create for that component. In the `@NgModule.providers` the service is application scoped, meaning only one instance for entire application